# Detect mouse position relevant to parent, rather than page

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset

I've got the below script which detects the position of the mouse relevant to the page, and accounts for a movement threshold of 100px, before registering the movement, allowing me to take actions.

```
// Keep track of last cursor positions
var cursorDistance = 0;
var lastCursorX = null;
var lastCursorY = null;

// On mousemove, take actions
section.on('mousemove', function(e){

    // Update last cursor positions to current positions
    var cursorX = e.clientX;
    var cursorY = e.clientY;
    var cursorThreshold = 100; // Amount of pixels cursor must move to register movement

    // Use Pythagorean theorem to calculate cursorDistance travelled (in any direction)
    if( lastCursorX ) cursorDistance += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lastCursorY - cursorY, 2) + Math.pow(lastCursorX - cursorX, 2));

    // Each time cursorDistance travelled is equal or more than cursorThreshold
    if( cursorDistance >= cursorThreshold ){
        //// Do something here within page

        // Reset cursor distance to restart tracking
        cursorDistance = 0;
    }

    // Update last cursor positions to current positions to restart tracking
    lastCursorX = e.clientX;
    lastCursorY = e.clientY;
}
```

However, I need to adjust this to track the mouse position relevant to the parent element (rather than the page), which does work to some extent but the threshold of 100px is now ignored) and actions are taken with every pixel moved.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: The only difference in the 2 is vars cursorX and cursor Y, so I think my calculations here must be incorrect?

```
// Keep track of last cursor positions
var cursorDistance = 0;
var lastCursorX = null;
var lastCursorY = null;

// On mousemove, take actions
section.on('mousemove', function(e){

    // Update last cursor positions to current positions
    var cursorX = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
    var cursorY = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
    var cursorThreshold = 100; // Amount of pixels cursor must move to register movement

    // Use Pythagorean theorem to calculate cursorDistance travelled (in any direction)
    if( lastCursorX ) cursorDistance += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lastCursorY - cursorY, 2) + Math.pow(lastCursorX - cursorX, 2));

    // Each time cursorDistance travelled is equal or more than cursorThreshold
    if( cursorDistance >= cursorThreshold ){
        //// Do something here within parent

        // Reset cursor distance to restart tracking
        cursorDistance = 0;
    }

    // Update last cursor positions to current positions to restart tracking
    lastCursorX = e.clientX;
    lastCursorY = e.clientY;
}
```

Comment: What's a section then? Could you post your html?

Comment: Hi @michal.materowski, the section is the area within the overall page where I want the effect to take place, rather than relative to the entire page, I want to detect mousevents relative to this only.

Comment: Alright, I think I got you. It's still hard to reason about where mistake is, since I don't know what do you assign to lastCursorX and lastCursor Y variables

Comment: Have just updated the question showing how these are updated during the mousemove event, hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks! I've checked it out in plunker and actions are only recorded for #section element. When I move my mouse over other elements there's no calculation. Also threshold seems to work correctly. Am I missing something, could you take a look? https://playcode.io/789267/

Comment: Thanks @michal.materowski - oddly seems to be OK in your example, have you tried outputting the cursor co-ordinates in the console to check they are relative to your section? And not the page?

Comment: I updated the plunker with console.logs. The error seems to occur when cursorX or cursorY get the negative value (offset is bigger). That's when your distance algorithm fails, can You think of a way to improve it or do You still need more help?

Comment: Thanks. Unsure of an obvious way to improve it, as what I'm doing within the section is tracking images to the cursor position, so naturally those images are quite large. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will track the mouse only when it moves over an element.

```
section.on('mousemove', function (e) {
var cursorX = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
var cursorY = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
var cursorThreshold = 100; // Amount of pixels cursor must move to register movement 

if (lastCursorX) cursorDistance += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lastCursorY - cursorY, 2) + Math.pow(lastCursorX - cursorX, 2));
if (cursorDistance >= cursorThreshold) {
  cursorDistance = 0;
}
lastCursorX = cursorX;
lastCursorY = cursorY;
```

})

If you need to track more elements You'd probably want to reset lastCursorX and lastCursorY at some point

Comment: Excellent, thanks @michal.materowski! The trick seems to be those bottom two lines, as otherwise the cusrsorThreshold variable is ignored (and actions take place every 1px). Thanks so much for your help.